# Wifi AP/Router used as Repeater won't connect after replacing modem

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

At a loss and this product has absolutely no support options. I have a Seaidea 300 Mbps Wifi router (Wireless-N) being used to boost wifi signal to the upstairs rooms. One fun day, the main router stopped working and purchased a replacement as both router/modem were out dated.

Now I have a dual modem/router Arris Surfboard SB6580-G228. The wireless signal is still not great and I can't get it to reconnect. I've tried connecting wired and wireless, still unable to get to the login screen through the IP address it is instructing to go to. I tried resetting the repeater to no avail. Does anyone have any tips on reconnecting the repeater/router?

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the wireless-n AP/repeater. Hold the reset for a few moments. You can connect wirelessly from your phone or whichever wireless device you use. Connect to Wi-Fi called wireless-n. Then from your browser type in the IP address that's on back of the AP/repeater.

You should have the login screen. User and password are both `admin`. Then click on repeater. It will scan for Wi-Fi signals to connect to. Pick the one you want to boost. When it goes to the next page change the SSID to the SSID of the network you chose. Put in your password and click save and reboot. You should be good to go.